# Hover event incorrectly triggers

Tags: c#, winforms

New to stack overflow so hoping someone knows what's going wrong here.

For some reason whenever I hover over a button in my c# forms application, it causes a reset in my code. This seems weird to me considering I don't actually have any hover events on the button. I even tried adding another button and even when I do nothing to it, hovering still causes the reset.

The program is supposed to fill up the tank with colors and the color can be changed while it is filling up. Once it is filled up it resets to empty. It should start filling the next time the slider governing fill speed is interacted with.

It does this correctly but it also starts filling again when I hover over the button.

```
namespace Assignment5A
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public float streamHeight = 370;
        public float lastWaterHeight = 0;
        public float waterHeight = 0;
        public float waterBottom = 500;
        public float fillSpeed = 300;

        public Color brushColor = Color.LightBlue;
        public Graphics g;
        public Pen pen;
        public Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue);

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 500;
            this.Height =600;
            this.BackColor = Color.Black;
            SpeedTimer.Interval = (int)fillSpeed;
        }

        private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            g = e.Graphics;
            pen = new Pen(Color.White);
            g.DrawLine(pen, 50, 200, 50, 500);
            g.DrawLine(pen, 350, 200, 350, 500);
            g.DrawLine(pen, 50, 500, 350, 500);

            SpeedTimer.Start();
        }

        private void SpeedTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (waterHeight < 270)
            {
                brush = new SolidBrush(brushColor);
                g = this.CreateGraphics();

                g.FillRectangle(brush, 108, 136, 20, waterBottom - 136 - waterHeight);
                waterHeight += 1f;
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 51, waterBottom - waterHeight, 299, waterHeight - lastWaterHeight);
                lastWaterHeight = waterHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                SpeedTimer.Stop();
                waterHeight = 0;
                lastWaterHeight = 0;
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 51, 136, 299, 364);
            }
        }

        private void Speed_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (waterHeight < 270)
            {
                float scrollValue = Speed.Value;
                fillSpeed = 300 / scrollValue;
                SpeedTimer.Interval = (int)fillSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 51, 230, 299, 270);
                SpeedTimer.Start();
            }
        }

        private void ColorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetColor.ShowDialog();
            brushColor = SetColor.Color;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. I've taken the liberty of removing the `visual-studio` tag because the tag is intended for questions about Visual Studio itself (as opposed to code you write using VS).

Comment: It's probably the Paint event kicking in when hovered. Is that where the "reset" happens?

Comment: Is there any chance you can provide a video of what's happening? It seems to be working fine on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my first answer was completely wrong, must have read the question wrong, sorry.

The answer still comes down to your `MainForm_Paint` event, though. This event is fired whenever the form is drawn or redrawn, and includes anything on it (like your buttons). When your mouse hovers over an element it needs to be redrawn, as well as any of its parents, right back to the form level. It also occurs if the form is resized, comes back into view after being hidden (either partially or completely), goes off screen and comes back on, etc, etc.  Lots of different things will trigger a form's `Paint` event to fire.  And in your `MainForm_Paint` event, you have this line:

```
SpeedTimer.Start();
```

...which causes the timer to start and everything starts all over again.

Instead of using `MainForm_Paint`, I'd probably suggest you use the form's `Load` event to set up all these initial conditions.  That will only fire once after the form has initialised and is shown on screen.

Comment: Thanks for going to the effort of responding! Really appreciate it. Really bugged me what was going on so it's awesome to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Stack OVerflow! If this has answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer and optionally upvote if you feel so inclined. This helps me and improves this for others who may come in future looking for similar answers.  Good luck with your programming adventures.